# What is the purpose/benefit of using ignored parameters in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just so there is no misunderstanding, this question is not about allowing for optional parameters in a JS function.

My question is motiviated by the jQuery `parseXML` function, which is defined in `jQuery.js` as follows:

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
// (xml & tmp used internally)
parseXML: function( data, xml, tmp ) { 
   ... 
}
```

Within the body of the function, the parameters `xml` and and `tmp` are both assigned before they are used. That means they are being used as local variables, so the function could have been defined like this:

```
parseXML: function(data) { 
   var xml, tmp;
   ... 
}
```

What is the benefit of doing it the first way, other than saving a few characters in the minified version of `jQuery.js`?

Comment: @fireeyedboy - Since they are set before being accessed, I'm not sure how they could be used for recursion.  I think Joel has correctly identified the answer to his own question - to save a few characters.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - parseXML is not recursive

Comment: @Joel: alright, well at least we've got that sorted out then. :)

Comment: @Ender: considering that the following is not uncommon in recursive functions: `function recursiveFunction( $node, $level = 0 )` in other languages, and setting default values for parameters is not allowed in Javascript like this, I can very well imagine a recursive function in Javascript initiating the optional parameters. However, in many cases a simple check for `undefined` (or was it `null`? I keep mixing those up in Javascript) would probably be sufficient.

Comment: @Ender - I was wondering if there might be some performance difference. Seems like it would be minimal, but I don't know.

Comment: maybe because the writer don't want to write var statement. less space. its and internal variable(private). it really wasn't used for initial value or anything.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it was an oversight that never got caught.

Comment: @gshauger: It is commented in the code that they are used internally only, so this is intentional. I am leaning toward what I stated at the bottom of may question, namely, to save a few characters when minified. Becuase jQuery is used in many web pages, it is important to reduce load time. I am waiting to see if there is some other reason (e.g. performance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we define two functions...

```
function a ( foo ) { }
function b ( foo, bar, baz ) {}
```

...they'll report different [`length`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)...

```
console.log( [a.length, b.length] ); // logs [1, 3]
```

It's very rare to see [this little known feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of javascript used.

But apart from shaving a couple of bytes off the minified file-size, this is the only other reason that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you might add unused parameters to a function to conform to some pre-agreed function signature, if you're going to pass this function to another function as a callback or continuation, and the API contract says "I call your callback with these parameters", and you don't need all the parameters to do what you want to do in the callback. (This would apply to any language, not just JavaScript.)

In this specific case, I don't know. How is parseXML used; is it called directly, or used as an argument to other functions which might expect a 3-argument function?

Comment: That's not it either. JavaScript doesn't care if you don't pass all the params it expects, or if you pass more than it expects.  Have a look at this demo for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/aEgyF/

Comment: Yeah, I believe you without looking for proof. I was just describing reasons you *might* do that, though I guess in JS this isn't a valid one. (Also, I went and looked at the jQuery.js source and answered my own question about how parseXML is used: it can be used as an argument to other functions, but AFAICT they'd only pass the first argument.)

Answer (score 1):

`(xml & tmp used internally)`

You misunderstand the meaning. They do not mean "internally" within the function. They mean internally within the library. The public API of this function has one parameter (data). The private API of this function has 3 parameters.

This is common throughout jQuery. In general these functions can work with and without side effects. The API without side effects is public and jQuery itself will pass in more parameters to cause side effects that you as a user should not be doing.

Comment: +1 for clarifying the intended meaning of "used internally". Basically, then, some functions have optional parameters that are not part of the public API. However, in the case of `parseXML`, the "extra" parameters cannot cause side effects because they are overwritten before they are used. Perhaps they were used to cause side effects in an earlier version.